Discrepancy between AC analysis and transient analysis in LTspice
I'm trying to understand the discrepancy between AC analysis and transient analysis in LTspice.
I have the following circuit:

Nothing complicated. Just a 2V voltage source feeding a signal through a 10k resistor to a pair of parallel opposite diodes connected to GND.
When I run transient analysis with a 2V sine @ 1kHz, I get the following results which seem both intuitive and correct:

The voltage at point A has an amplitude of 2V as expected, and the voltage at point B has an amplitude of roughly 500mV due to the clipping diodes.
But when I run AC analysis I get these results:

I'm assuming that the drop after 10kHz is due to the RC filter formed by R1 and the intrinsic capacitance of D1 and D2,
but how come both A and B are at roughly +6dB @ 1kHz? I would have expected A at +6dB and B at -6dB.
A little help understanding the observed discrepancy would be appreciated.

AC analysis is small signal analysis. Such linear analysis doesn't notice clipping or non-linear PN junctions. The diodes might look like resistors/capacitors in AC analysis if they were biased with a DC current source through them. But if you don't do that that, then those diodes will be treated with $0:\text{V}$ across them. Meaning zero current through them. Meaning -- well, I think you see what that means -- no current through your resistor. So no voltage drop. So end of story.

When LTspice does AC analysis, it first calculates the DC operating point as it would for the initial operating point for a transient analysis. In your case, that is 0V, since the sine wave is 0V at t=0.
Then it uses the linearized response about that operating point to calculate the complex node voltages. Whatever you set for magnitude of the AC voltage is ignored except for scaling the  output results, so you may as well use 1V when doing an AC analysis.
That means that you'll get nonsensical results if your circuit is not at least approximately linear at the actual voltage levels in use. It won't model clipping or distortion.
So, if you don't have a good understanding of the circuit behavior it's best to do a transient analysis first to make sure it's not too nonlinear. In your case, you are expecting the nonlinear response, of course.

When doing an AC analysis, a simulator will set a convenient bias point (usually 0 volts and almost certainly so in your example) and use an AC level that is quite small to derive the output. It will then scale the output with respect to the input level to produce a realistic output voltage should 1 volt have been used for the input signal.
Reason: AC analysis does not and can not take into account circuits with non-linearities; that's what transient analysis is for.
